# Change the color of buttons designed by table with CSS

Tags: css, button, css-tables

Considering the following code displaying two different buttons structured by a table (`<tbody class="btn btn-left">` is a button and `<tbody class="btn btn-right">` is another button:

```
<table>
<tbody class="btn btn-left">
  <tr>
     <td class="btn-tl"></td>
     <td class="btn-tc"></td>
     <td class="btn-tr"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="btn-ml"></td>
     <td class="btn-mc"></td>
     <td class="btn-mr"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="btn-bl"></td>
     <td class="btn-bc"></td>
     <td class="btn-br"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table>
<tbody class="btn btn-right">
  <tr>
     <td class="btn-tl"></td>
     <td class="btn-tc"></td>
     <td class="btn-tr"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="btn-ml"></td>
     <td class="btn-mc"></td>
     <td class="btn-mr"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="btn-bl"></td>
     <td class="btn-bc"></td>
     <td class="btn-br"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The css is working but doesn't target the td, which I need to

```
.btn-left {
    background-color: red;
    border-color: red;
}

.btn-right {
    background-color: blue;
    border-color: blue;
}
```

How would you set up the css so that one button displays a color and the other button displays another color ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Colour of what exactly? Why are you using a table to display a button? What's your existing CSS?

Comment: target them through css - From The Mysterious Soul

Comment: @JanHančič I'm trying to change the color of the background and the border of all the `<tr>` and `<td>` within a `<tbody>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at first - you must use the table tag.

Then put following classes in your Stylesheet:

```
.btn-left { color: blue; }
.btn-right { color: red; }
```

[a liddle fiddle](https://jsbin.com/yatajoteyu/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Thanks, this is close. I've edited my post. Basically I need to target the td as well

Comment: Ha ! I didn't know about the function of css combinators and I needed to do a simple `tbody.btn-left > tr > td`. Thank you for your kindness and help!